# Como salvar tabela de checkbox PHP Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

possuo uma "tabela de checkbox" e preciso salvar ela no BD, obviamente depois precisarei mostrar, mas não sei o melhor jeito para fazer isso, estou esgotado do serviço e não consigo pensar direito.

Segue o código:

```js
$("#addCronogramaFisico").click(function(){
  addCronogramaFisico();
})

i=0;
function addCronogramaFisico(){
  var j = i+13;
  tableFisico = ""+
  "<tr bgcolor='#F0F0F0'>"+
    "<td><input type='text' name='novoCronogramaFisico[]' placeholder='Digite o novo Cronograma'></td>";
  for(i;i<j;i++){
    tableFisico += ""+
      "<td>"+
        "<section title='.squaredTwo'>"+
          "<div class='squaredTwo'>"+
            "<input type='checkbox' value='none' id='squareCF"+i+"' name='cb[]'>"+
            "<label for='squareCF"+i+"'></label>"+
          "</div>"+
        "</section>"+
      "</td>";

  }
  tableFisico += ""+
  "<td align='center'><img width='18' class='imgDel' src='../img/minus.png'></td>"+
  "</tr>";

  $("#projetoFisicoFixo").append(tableFisico);
  removeCronogramaFisico();
}

function removeCronogramaFisico(){
  $(".imgDel").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().html("");
    // console.log($(this).parent().parent().parent());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p align="center" class="dest">Cronograma Físico:<span class="instrucoes">(Tempo necessário para cada fase do projeto para atingir os objetivos)</span><img width="18" src="../img/plus.png" id="addCronogramaFisico"></p>
        <table width="520" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="projetoFisicoFixo">
        <tr>
          <th>Mês</th>
          <th>12</th>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
          <th>3</th>
          <th>4</th>
          <th>5</th>
          <th>6</th>
          <th>7</th>
          <th>8</th>
          <th>9</th>
          <th>10</th>
          <th>11</th>
          <th>12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Estruturação do Plano</td>
          <? for($i=0;$i<13;$i++){ ?>
          <td>
            <section title=".squaredTwo">
              <div class="squaredTwo">
                <input type="checkbox" value="" id="squareEP<?=$i?>" name="cf0[]" />
                <label for="squareEP<?=$i?>"></label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Apresentação do plano a Direção</td>
          <? for($i=0;$i<13;$i++){ ?>
          <td>
            <section title=".squaredTwo">
              <div class="squaredTwo">
                <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squareAP<?=$i?>" name="cf1[]" />
                <label for="squareAP<?=$i?>"></label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Encaminhamento à Gerência de Projetos SMED</td>
          <? for($i=0;$i<13;$i++){ ?>
          <td>
            <section title=".squaredTwo">
              <div class="squaredTwo">
                <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squareEG<?=$i?>" name="cf2[]" />
                <label for="squareEG<?=$i?>"></label>
              </div>
            </section>
          </td>
          <? } ?>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

O código não executa porque tem php no meio, mas é só copiar para um server.

minha table atual para guardar está assim:

```
CREATE TABLE educacao.cronograma_fisico
(
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_projeto INTEGER REFERENCES educacao.projetos ON DELETE CASCADE,
  id_descricao varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ano varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  mes0 boolean,
  mes1 boolean,
  mes2 boolean,
  mes3 boolean,
  mes4 boolean,
  mes5 boolean,
  mes6 boolean,
  mes7 boolean,
  mes8 boolean,
  mes9 boolean,
  mes10 boolean,
  mes11 boolean,
  mes12 boolean,
  user_alteracao varchar(50),
  dt_alteracao date,
  hr_alteracao character(5)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
```

Enfim, qual a melhor forma para conseguir pegar esses checkbox e salvá-los no BD? Lembrando que preciso salvar o nome da linha também. Gracias

Comment: Você precisa submeter os dados dessa tabela para o PHP como se fosse um form é isso ? Vai usar AJAX para essa submissão ?

Comment: A ideia era submeter normalmente por um form, pois existem outros dados antes desta parte!